# como usar atributos dentro de una funcion javascript

Tags: javascript

Tengo una función javascript a la cual le paso un parámetro, y dentro de esa función quiero modificar un atributo de ese parámetro, pero no lo consigo. Mi código es el siguiente:

Este es el código desde el que llamo a mi función (que es un cuadro de dialogo)

```
mostrarDialogoBorrar([[#{dialogo_confirm_borrar_indice}]], nombreCampo);
```

Esta es mi función que muestra el cuadro de dialogo, que tiene dos botones. Cuando selecciono uno de los botones quiero que se cambie el atributo Checked del checkbox que tiene como id = nombreCampo

```
function mostrarDialogoBorrar(texto, nombreCampo){
     document.getElementById("dialog-confirm-generic").innerHTML=texto;
     alert( $(  "#nombreCampo" ));
     $( "#dialog-confirm-generic" ).dialog({
         resizable: false,
         height:160,
         modal: true,
         position: [($(window).width() / 2) - 150, 300],
         dialogClass: 'DeleteConfirmDialog',
         buttons: {                                 
             [[#{dialogo_confirm_table_button_continuar}]]: function() {
                 $( this ).dialog("close");
             },
             [[#{dialogo_confirm_delete_button_cancelar}]]: function() {
                 $( '#' + nombreCampo ).attr('checked', true);
                 $( this ).dialog("close");
             }
         }

     });
 }
```

La linea que no funciona es la siguiente:

```
$( '#' + nombreCampo ).attr('checked', true);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ya esta, solo tuve que cambiar la línea que daba problemas por:

```
document.getElementById(nombreCampo).checked=true;
```

Comment: Bien! Cuando puedas regresa y acepta tu propia respuesta para que no quede como pendiente.

Comment: Deberías ser consistente en tu código. Si estás usando jquery deberías usar siempre jQuery para hacer manipulaciones al DOM. Los frameworks eliminan inconsistencias introducidas entre los distintos navegadores. Si ya escogiste un framework úsalo. Lee http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/166273/advantages-of-using-pure-javascript-over-jquery

Comment: @devconcept si bien utiliza jQuery como parte del proyecto, no es obligatorio que resuelva todo con jQuery. Además, este código JavaScript funciona en cualquier navegador.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza La razón puesta en el comentario anterior es válida porque es una buena práctica. Chequea la documentación de [$.prop](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) y lee las notas que usan precisamente la propiedad `checked` para que veas porqué. Caer en un bug usando un atributo booleano es muy fácil en javascript.

Comment: @devconcept concuerdo contigo, pero mi punto es que esta no es una mala solución.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Yo tambien hacia mix de código pero luego de entender como usar los frameworks los bugs se redujeron un 25%. La respuesta es buena en efecto. Usar jquery es una simple sugerencia. La OP se dará cuenta si se empieza a encontrar con bugs por usar los atributos de esta forma.

Answer (score 2):

En Jquery, según la versión, podría ser algo así:

```
$( '#' + nombreCampo ).prop("checked", true);
```